# validation message using regular expression visible after correction-MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am working on a MVC project.I have a textbox accepting phone number,which shows a mask on control activation like (   )-   -    .This mask thing is written in javascript in the layout,as to work for the whole project.

```
<script>
    $('input[data-val=true]').on('blur', function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".phone").mask("(999)-999-9999");
    });
</script>
```

and my model is

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
 [RegularExpression(@"^(?!0{10})\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.●]?([0-9]{3})[-.●]([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Phone must not contain all zeros")]      
 [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = " {0} can be maximum 16 characters")]
 public string Phone { get; set; }
```

and view

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.Phone,new{Class="form-control phone"})
```

It is not accepting all zeros but the error message stays even after correction, which is not allowing to save

Comment: Aren't you getting **exception** in view? It should be `@class` instead of `Class`

Comment: no exception in the view..it is working fine

Comment: I've created a **[fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rMAQJ)** for you.. Could you tell how to replicate? I feel its working fine there..

Comment: enter all zeros..then it will show error message.replace the zeros by numbers..error message is still visible